# Issue with returning records back to a web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, .net-2.0

I am having some issues in attempting to display a recordset from my webservice.

Currently my application involves a client feeding their values into my webservice.
The webservice will then call a vb.net database class, which executes a SQL stored procedure, returns a recordset to the database class, and the class will pass the recordset back to the webservice, which will display it to the client in xml.

The problem I am having passing the recordset from the database class back to the webservice in a format that can be sent back to the client. I can't seem to convert the recordset to string format. Would it be better to have the record returned in XML format?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think .NET has already done most of the work for you. If your vb.net class returns a DATASET object, you already have an XML object. You may want to do some transformations on it, but the XML is already there.

Look for the dataset.GetXML method.